# Why is the predict() function recycling the same four values for my GLM?

Tags: r, glm, predict, mle

I made a fairly simple binomial regression model:

```
m_r <- mle2(ig$v ~ dbinom(size=ig$n, prob = 1/(1+exp(-(a + br * ig$river_dist)))),
    start = list(a = 0, br = 0), data = ig)
```

based on this dataframe:

```
> ig
    v   n ig_dist river_dist tam_dist       site
1 102 256     950       1040     1040     Boveda
2   1  11    4800        720      832 Cuchaconga
3  19  24    2000        475      475   Ishpingo
4  12  15    3400        611      800    La Joya
```

And now I'd like to graph predicted outcomes for a range of possible 'river_dist' values. To do that, I created a new dataframe:

```
newdat <- data.frame(river_dist=seq(min(ig$river_dist), max(ig$river_dist),len=100))
```

and tried to add predicted values based on the model:

```
newdat$v <- predict(m_r, newdata=newdat, type="response")
```

But it seems to be recycling the same four values over and over (short sample, but the numbers keep repeating):

```
> head(newdat)
  river_dist         v
1   475.0000 95.110424
2   480.7071  7.450936
3   486.4141 20.330167
4   492.1212 11.456229
5   497.8283 95.110424
6   503.5354  7.450936
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: By changing 'ig$river_dist' to 'river_dist' in my model, I'm able to produce what look like real predictions, but they're still following a four-value cycle (with slight variations each time), producing zigzags in my graph, rather than a slope or curve I was expecting. If someone could explain why, I'd appreciate it! My plotting:

```
plot(v~river_dist, data=ig, col="red4")
lines(v ~ river_dist, newdat, col="green4", lwd=2)
```

Comment: `predict(m_r, newdata=newdat, type="response")` only gives four values and these are thus recycled. But I don't know why there are only four values returned although you `newdat` data frame has 100 rows since I don't know this package.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was in the formula specification. You referred to the `river_dist` variable as `ig$river_dist` although you specified the data argument already. So the variable name used in the fitting process did not match the variable name of the data used for the `predict` function.

```
library(bbmle)

ig <- tibble::tribble(
    ~v,   ~n, ~ig_dist, ~river_dist, ~tam_dist,        ~site,
  102L, 256L,     950L,       1040L,     1040L,     "Boveda",
    1L,  11L,    4800L,        720L,      832L, "Cuchaconga",
   19L,  24L,    2000L,        475L,      475L,   "Ishpingo",
   12L,  15L,    3400L,        611L,      800L,    "La Joya"
  )

m_r <- mle2(ig$v ~ dbinom(size=ig$n, prob = 1/(1+exp(-(a + br * river_dist)))),
            start = list(a = 0, br = 0), data = ig)

newdat <- data.frame(river_dist=seq(min(ig$river_dist), max(ig$river_dist),len=100))

newdat$v <- predict(m_r, newdata=newdat, type="response")

head(newdat$v)

#> [1] 216.855114   9.285536  20.187424  12.571487 213.762248   9.150584
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved at least part of the problem. The numbers do still have a wacky cycle to them (c. 220, c. 9-10, c. 20, c. 12) that creates crazy zig-zags in my plot, rather than the gentle curve I was expecting. (I'll edit the post to show my plotting commands). That may be an issue with my modeling strategy, rather than the code itself? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes I see. No sorry no ideas, not familiar with this kind of modeling. Hope I could help anyway. Maybe try Cross Validated to get help with the modeling part.